# Confusion with getview android imagebuttons

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which has two image buttons in the row. Tapping image button change the background color. When I tap on the first list item, image button background change and the view is saved but scrolling bottom of the listview, background color of image button of another list item changes as well. Below is the getView of Custom Adapter. How can I avoid this problem?

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder = null;

    //view=null;
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.presentButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.absentButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
        holder.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);


        view.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    final SQLiteStudents db1 = new SQLiteStudents(activity.getApplicationContext());
    final TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    final TextView tvRoll = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roll);
    final studentInfo s = students.get(i);
    tvRoll.setText(s.getRoll() + ".");
    tvName.setText(s.getName());
    final Integer roll = Integer.parseInt(s.getRoll());
    //ivpresent.setBackgroundColor(0);
    final ViewHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
    //final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.presentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db1.updateUser(roll,"present");


            finalHolder1.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
            finalHolder1.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
            //v1.setTag(v.getTag());
            //Log.d("present","Roll No: "+String.valueOf(roll));
            finalHolder1.presentButton.setTag(Integer.toString(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    holder.absentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db1.updateUser(roll,"absent");
            finalHolder1.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
            finalHolder1.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(RED);
            //view=null;
            //Log.d("absent","Roll No: "+String.valueOf(roll));
            finalHolder1.presentButton.setTag(Integer.toString(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    return view;

}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageButton presentButton;
    public ImageButton absentButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<studentInfo> students;
    private boolean presentButton = false;
    private boolean absentButton = false;
```

> You need to add an else accordingly in your code, see below:

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder = null;

    //view=null;
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_list, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.presentButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        holder.absentButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        holder.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
        holder.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);


        view.setTag(holder);

    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    final SQLiteStudents db1 = new SQLiteStudents(activity.getApplicationContext());
    final TextView tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    final TextView tvRoll = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_roll);
    final studentInfo s = students.get(i);
    tvRoll.setText(s.getRoll() + ".");
    tvName.setText(s.getName());
    final Integer roll = Integer.parseInt(s.getRoll());
    //ivpresent.setBackgroundColor(0);
    final ViewHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
    //final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.presentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db1.updateUser(roll,"present");
            presentButton = true;
        }
    });
    holder.absentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db1.updateUser(roll,"absent");
            absentButton = true;

        }
    });

   if(presentButton){
    finalHolder1.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
            finalHolder1.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
            //v1.setTag(v.getTag());
            //Log.d("present","Roll No: "+String.valueOf(roll));
            finalHolder1.presentButton.setTag(Integer.toString(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
    //set button to some default button like black
   }

   if(absentButton){
    finalHolder1.presentButton.setBackgroundColor(0);
            finalHolder1.absentButton.setBackgroundColor(RED);
            //view=null;
            //Log.d("absent","Roll No: "+String.valueOf(roll));
            finalHolder1.presentButton.setTag(Integer.toString(i));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
    //set button to some default button like black
   }


    return view;

}
```

Comment: Adding code in else section crashes my application. Default color is null for both image buttons.. I want to highlight only pressed button and not other buttons in listview. My listview row consists of textview and 2 imagebuttons.. full code of customadapter in: [link](https://pastebin.com/SbTKWKLB)

Comment: I get the idea from your code, but still problem unsolved.. The above code returns error and expects: `final boolean[] presentButton = new boolean[1];` 
and when I run declaring imagebutton bool to final array, no button is highlighted after clicking on it.. :(

Comment: Thank you for supporting me however, I still get problem with the guide you provided. One of the imageButton on all list items are selected onScroll. I changed vew lines on the [code](https://pastebin.com/Uupxwt0q). but it gives me same error like previous.